# Passing variable to method as to add to generic arraylist - Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am wanting to take user data in one method and pass that data to an "add" method, as to add said data to a generic arraylist. However I receive the following error message...

> add (T) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

I'm not sure if this is a `static` problem or not...

My simplified code:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

void dataCollection() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("type data");
    add(scan.next());
}

void add(T t) {
    list.add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `String`s to your `List`, define it as a `List<String>`, not `List<T>`.

A `List<T>` might be (depending on how your class is instantiated), for example, a `List<Integer>`, which can't hold `String`s.

If you truly need your `List` to be generic, you shouldn't be adding `String`s to it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Eran. This is a first adventure into generics for me, so I'm still learning!